# Codeigniter 3 try to convert view into string but not works

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have try to convert my view into string like

```
/* User Chat Avatar */
    $data['avatar'] = $this->session->userdata('avatar');

    /* Widget Configuration Option*/
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('ID');
    $widgetData = $this->widgetModel->getWidgetData($user_id);
    $departmentData = $this->widgetModel->getDepartmentData($user_id);
    $data['widget'] = $widgetData;
    $data['department'] = $departmentData;

    $widgetTemplate = $this->load->view('widget_model_box', $data, TRUE);
    echo $widgetTemplate;
```

but this code is not convert my view template into string what is wrong here.. it show me browser output not string.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried return instead of echo. `return $widgetTemplate;` and you might need to remove the TRUE on view()

Comment: its showing me html output in browser not string, TRUE is giving string output and not sending view to browser. But in my case its not working....

Comment: if you echo it it will show you the html, think bout echo "<b>name</b>" will that echo as string in browser ? it will print name in bold

Answer (score -1):

Try with `echo strip_tags($widgetTemplate);`

Comment: This doesn't work. Produces error: Message:  strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: that error clears... you are passing object instead of a string.